# Union bound with two unions

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove that for a countable index set $I$ where $i \in I$ and $B_i \subset A_i$,
$$\mathbb{P}\left ( \bigcup_{i}^{}A_i \right ) - \mathbb{P}\left ( \bigcup_{i}^{}B_i \right ) \leq \sum_{i}^{}(\mathbb{P}(A_i) - \mathbb{P}(B_i)).$$
I thought we could just use the union bound and combine them, but I realize that is not going to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

(Looking for a hint, not solution)

Comment: Try showing $\cup_i A_i \setminus ( \cup_i B_i) \subset \cup_i( A_i \setminus B_i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x\in\cup_i A_i\backslash\cup_i B_i$ we have some $i_0$ such that $x\in A_{i_0}\backslash(\cup_iB_i)\subset A_{i_0}\backslash B_{i_0}$. Then use union bound.